# Error Message: "HomePage.jsx:12 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'rooms') at HomePage.jsx:12:1"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm accessing data from dummy JSON file using axios. I'm setting the incoming data to a state. When the component first mounts, I get the above error but, the second time when I make changes any random in file and the react app reloads, the data can be accessed successfully. (Note: I'm using functional component. I'm using recent versions.)

The line no. 13 works really fine but line no. 12 throws the given error

This is my HomePage Component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { callAPI } from '../utils/callAPI'

function HomePage() {
const \[roomDetails, setRoomDetails\] = useState(null)

    const showRoomDetails = () => {
        callAPI(`data/meetingRoom.json`)
        .then((data) => {
            setRoomDetails(data)
            console.log("Accessing roomDetails datadsada=>" + roomDetails.rooms[0].timeSlots.startTime[1]); //line 12
            console.log("Results is: " + data.rooms[0].timeSlots.startTime[0]); //line 13
        })
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        showRoomDetails()
            // calling the showRoomDetails() function when the component is rendered
    }, [])

return (
\<\>
\<h1 className='text-4xl'\>Welcome to online room booking system\</h1\>
\</\>
)
}

export default HomePage
```

This is my callAPI.js file,

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { BASE_URL } from './constants'

const config = {
headers: {
"Content-Type" : "application/json",    // this means a json we're sending a JSON object data in request body
"Accept" : "application/json"   // this mean client(here the callAPI function) will get data response in JSON format
}
}

export const callAPI = async (resource) =\> {
const { data } = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/${resource}`, config)
return data
}

// while calling the function, we'll send a resource as a string like `data/meetingRoom.json` to point to that file
```

Answer (score -1):

You encounter this error because the `setRoomDetails(data)` function doesn't immediately update the state variable `roomDetails`.

In other words, when you call `setRoomDetails(data)`, it schedules a state update, but the update doesn't happen instantly. React processes state updates asynchronously. So, at the moment when you execute the following code

```
console.log("Accessing roomDetails data => " + roomDetails.rooms[0].timeSlots.startTime[1]);
```

The `roomDetails` variable is still `null` because the state update hasn't completed yet. As a result, you encounter this error.
If you want to do something after the `roomDetails` state is updated, you should use `useEffect`.

https://initialcommit.com/blog/usestate-useeffect-hooks-react